# Why do I have to boot two times to get a usable Ubuntu?

Tags: boot, 16.04, grub-legacy

I recently installed Ubuntu 16.04, now it's the only operative system installed on my computer.

The problem I'm facing is like this, every time I shutdown my computer, the next time I want to turn it on, the first screen that appears is the following

[image]

The computer this time, never asks me for what option do I want to select when booting, it just runs Ubuntu (or that's what I think). But after this screen disappears, the screen turns black, and I can't use it properly, but it is turned on, because the lights are on, and when I keep pressed the on/off button, the computer turns off.

Then, after this, I try to turn it on again, and this new time, I'm faced with a different screen, one that lets me select what do I want to do, like this:

[image]

This time I can select to open Ubuntu normally, and everything goes fine. I always can get to use the computer, but it's annoying that I have to 'turn it on' two times to do it.

Maybe it helps to know that before this Ubuntu 16.04, I have installed Windows 10 and Ubuntu 14.04 in dual boot, and that I think I installed Ubuntu 16.04 in legacy mode.

My question is, how can this happen, and what would you recommend me to read/research to solve this issue?

Thank you so much.

Comment: If you only have Ubuntu, it does not show grub menu, but just directly boots. And if Ubuntu is not shutdown normally, on next reboot it will show grub menu so you have the option to boot recovery mode. And it may  be related to use of grub2's BIOS boot versions rather than an UEFI install. UEFI wants to boot in UEFI mode and only when that fails and you have settings to allow CSM/Legacy/BIOS boot will it then also try BIOS boot mode. You do not have grub legacy which has not been used with Ubuntu as standard since 9.10 (Oct 2009). What brand/model system. Did you install in CSM/Legacy mode?

Comment: 16.04 should have grub `2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.14` if all is normal. I don't see that above.

Comment: @oldfred I think I installed it in csm/legacy mode.

Comment: Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info